# Using apollo client (or some alternative) server-side to get autocompletion and syntax highlighting

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, graphql, apollo

I am currently using standard `fetch` in my server to query my graphql api. This works, but there is no graphql syntax highlighting / autocomplete and I am unable to use tools such as https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=apollographql.vscode-apollo

My immediate idea was to use apollo-client on the server, however I am unable to figure out if it is possible to set it up without cache and in a lightweight manner.

Perhaps there are some other alternatives for this besides apollo client, that enhance developer experience from just using normal `fetch()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the [GraphQL extension by Prisma instead](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Prisma.vscode-graphql#review-details). In addition to supporting `.graphql` files and `gql` tag detection, it allows you to add syntax highlighting to any string by just appending a comment:

```
const query = /* GraphQL */ `
  query {
    hello
  }
`
```